# Building a DC circuit that produces output voltage from 1 to 10 in 1V increments

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, circuit-design, low-power

I have been trying to design a DC circuit that can produce a range of output voltage from 1 to 10 in 1 voltage increments with just (non-inverting) operational amplifiers, switches, resistors, and grounds. The voltage source is a 5V battery. I built one but it uses 9 resistors and 7 switches while the power loss is great in all the range of voltage. How could one design one that is efficient (lower power loss & less number of the components)?

[image]

Above is the design I came up with but I do not think it's satisfactory. Like Jonathan said in the reply, I know it could be done with just 4 switches, but I could not figure out how and I need help.

Comment: Please show your schematic and indicate what power supplies you are using.

Comment: Note that you need to _edit your question_.  While you're at it, tell us how accurate you want it to be, and what you're going to hook up to it -- something that just needs to read correctly on a voltmeter is very different from something that needs to drive a motor, for instance, especially if you want it to stay within millivolts of its nominal voltage output.

Comment: You will not be generating 10 V from a `5 V battery` with a "passive" or "linear" circuit: You need to design it to achieve that goal. Approaches include *charge pumps* and *step-up converters*.

Comment: How much output current do you need?

Comment: @winny output voltage needs to be 1v, 2v, 3v, ..., 10v by switch control.

Comment: Yes, but how much _current_?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an [R-2R resistor ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder) followed by an OpAmp buffer. What you want to build is called a digital-to-analog converter (DAC). You will need 4 switches.

Note that you will of course need a supply voltage that's bigger than your maximum output voltage. If you want up to 10V at the output, a 12V or 15V supply would work well.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I did some digging around R-2R resistors ladder and used OpAmp to jump to the voltage from 5V to 16V and designed a 4-bit R-2R circuit. Thank you for the hint @Jonathan-S. . But instead of a regular switch, I had to use spdt switches to make it 4. Did I do it correctly or am I missing anything?

Comment: The Opamp can not generate the voltage, he must get a higher voltage on his supply input to be able to have 16V at his output he need ~18.5V, it depends on which OpAmp you are using, they are all different. Do not answer on your own question if you do not have the solution. You can edit your question and make it more clear, show what you have improved since the last time!